# Syntax Error occured in Insert into query(MS Access)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, insert, ms-access-2007, syntax-error, vb.net-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and MS Access 2007

I can't fix the error

when debugging, *"Syntax error in Insert Into"* is occurred but sql syntax is correct
I'm new to vb.net and it would be grateful if anyone can give me a solution.

```vb
   Try
        Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO User([ID],[StudName],Address])VALUES('002','haerth','col')"
        Dim comLib As New OleDbCommand
        With comLib
            .CommandText = query
            .Connection = conLib
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        MessageBox.Show("Added Successfully")
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bracket mismatch:  Address]